# Реализовать возможность панорамной съемки

Tags: android, android-sdk, android-camera

Здравствуйте, стоит задача реализации возможности съёмки панорамного фото в Android приложении. Сейчас в приложении вызывается просто стандартная камера через intent. Необходимо сделать свою имплементацию с возможностью отслеживания дрожания при съемке и, при необходимости, сообщать об этом пользователю, и заставлять делать фото заново. Подскажите, в какую сторону копать, искал инфу, говорят что такая возможность есть только при условии наличия некоторых библиотек, которые устанавливаются вендором устройства, но, везде их названия разные. Может есть какие сторонние библиотеки? В идеале, реализовать, как на CyanogenMod 13 (ведётся камера из точки A в точку B, как при съемке видео) а на выходе получается ровная, хорошего качества фотография без артефактов склеивания.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Очень интересная [статья](https://software.intel.com/ru-ru/articles/fast-panorama-stitching), может помочь в вашей ситуации.

Comment: Спасибо. Но, хотелось бы уйти от использования OpenCV, т.к. для его работы на устройство необходимо устанавливать OpenCV Manger, чего хотелось бы избежать.

Comment: @AlexanderLomovskiy ну попробуйте "полазать" в каких нибудь git проектах что-ли https://github.com/yankeppey/PanoramaSample может найдёте что нибудь интересное.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы посоветовал выводить камеру на канвас через серфейс, подписаться на данные с датчиков и отслеживать поведение пользователя(дрожание и т.п.) Хорошая статья есть тут: [maohao](https://maohao.wordpress.com/2009/09/30/canvas-save-canvas-restore/)

Вероятнее всего вам поможет git, например:

https://github.com/zarelaky/panoramagl-android
или
https://github.com/ashqal/MD360Player4Android

Comment: На сколько я понял, эти библиотеки служат для реализации возможности просмотра панорамных фото и видео? А мне необходимо создать панорамное фото.